# How to declare data type as Timestamp in ios - swift

Tags: swift, firebase, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

I am a new iOS programming. I am creating a simple which integrate with `Firestore`. In `Firestore` i created collection and each documents contains many fields.

I have added `Timestamp` field in my document. And when i create model in `xcode` how can i declare my variable as `Timestamp` because i need to sort data on `tableView` base on `Timestamp`.

This is how `Timestamp` in `Firestore` looks like:

`September 17, 2018 at 3:37:43 PM UTC+7`

So, How can i write program and get current `Timestamp` like showing in `Firestore`

This is in programming:

```
struct RecentCallModel {

var call_answered: Bool?
var call_extension: String?
var call_type: String?
var details: String?
var duration:  String?
var title: String?
// How can i declare as Timestamp
var timestamp: ???

init(call_answered: Bool, call_extension: String, call_type: String, details: String , duration: String, timestamp: String,  title: String) {

    self.call_answered = call_answered
    self.call_extension = call_extension
    self.call_type = call_type
    self.details = details
    self.title = title
 }


}
```

Comment: simple use `Double`

Comment: how can I get current `Timestamp` in programming??

Comment: Firestore should return that field as `Timestamp` type. You can get a `Date` by using `.dateValue()` method on it

Comment: See the documentation found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp#/c:objc(cs)FIRTimestamp(im)dateValue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not acquainted with Firebase. But usually, in iOS, we store timestamps as `TimeInterval` which are type alias for `Double`.

```
class func getDateOnly(fromTimeStamp timestamp: TimeInterval) -> String { 
  let dayTimePeriodFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dayTimePeriodFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current 
  dayTimePeriodFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy - h:mm:ss a z" 
  return dayTimePeriodFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp)) 
}
```

Comment: Try NSDate or Simply Date variable. That should work

Comment: So, How can i write program and get current `Timestamp` like showing in `Firestore`

Comment: Try this method
class func getDateOnly(fromTimeStamp timestamp: TimeInterval) -> String {
        let dayTimePeriodFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dayTimePeriodFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        dayTimePeriodFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd YYYY"
        return dayTimePeriodFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp))
    }

Comment: Youll have to change the dateFormat obviously. But before that are you sure this it is a timestamp that Firestore returns you and not a date. Fundamentally they are two different things you know.

Comment: Okay! Let me try those method

Comment: In `Firestore` it stores data type as `Timestamp` and then in programming i declare variable as `Double`. How can I set data to the `Firestore` if data type is difference?

Comment: as per the link https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp#/c:objc(cs)FIRTimestamp(im)dateValue 
Timestamp is an epoch. which means youll need a Double to store it at your end

Comment: Just go for hit and run. If something is wrong for example mismatch of variable types. Then the compiler will inform you. You might as well learn something new :)

Comment: Yeah! Thank for your explanation.. I will try my best

Answer (score 2):

This is method how can we get current date and time in swift. and you also can declare timestamp as `Double` but i am not sure

```
// get the current date and time
let currentDateTime = Date()

// initialize the date formatter and set the style
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.timeStyle = .medium
formatter.dateStyle = .long

// get the date time String from the date object
formatter.string(from: currentDateTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what does your question explicitly imply, but you typically declare a timestamp value as a `Double`, something along the lines of `var timestamp: Double`. The retrieved data will look something like this 1537187800, and can be converted to an actual date and/or time using the following helper class

```
class DateAndTimeHelper {

static func convert(timestamp: Double, toDateFormat dateFormat: String) -> String {

        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp)
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
            dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat

        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)

    }

}
```

Which can be used using the following syntax

```
var timestamp: Double = 0.0

// Perform some database querying action in order to retrieve the actual timestamp value from the server
DateAndTimeHelper.convert(timestamp: timestamp, toDateFormat: DATE_FORMAT)
```

Note that you should replace DATE_FORMAT by the format you'd want to follow. A good reference of the available formats can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKM8N_8.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak05616_.htm).

Comment: In Firestore it stores data type as Timestamp and then in programming i declare variable as Double. How can I set data to the Firestore if data type is difference?